# Laravel server closes after starting it up

Tags: php, laravel

So I created a Laravel project and tried to boot it up,
however every time I do so it closes down again

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:20 2022] PHP 7.4.27 Development Server (http://localhost:8000) started
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:42 2022] [::1]:55208 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:42 2022] [::1]:55209 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:42 2022] [::1]:55208 Closing
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:42 2022] [::1]:55209 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Sat Jan 15 13:27:42 2022] [::1]:55209 Closing
```

I tried changing the port to 9000 but that also didn't work

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:9000
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:02 2022] PHP 7.4.27 Development Server (http://localhost:9000) started
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:16 2022] [::1]:54118 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:16 2022] [::1]:54119 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:16 2022] [::1]:54118 Closing
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:17 2022] [::1]:54119 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:17 2022] [::1]:54119 Closing
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:19 2022] [::1]:54125 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:19 2022] [::1]:54126 Accepted
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:19 2022] [::1]:54125 Closing
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:20 2022] [::1]:54126 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Sat Jan 15 13:30:20 2022] [::1]:54126 Closing
```

does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: It sounds like you have another instance of PHP running but it's hard to tell from your post. Have you looked inside the log files in the PHP directory ? If you run `php --ini` you will find your php install directory, logs should be there.

Comment: when you say `it closes down again` do you mean the command exits with an error or you are referring to the message `Closing` that's shown ?

Comment: @Sterre,  try to run `.env` App Url  path

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem, it's working fine. By the closing in logs, it means it's closing the specific connection.

Here's a log from my laravel install [image]